# Connect an array to a dropdown list;

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to associate an array of JSON objects to a drop down list and I do not understand how to initialize the array to the dropdown. I have tried this:

```
 function Save() {
    colors.nextColor.push({
    "name": document.getElementById("name").value,
    "rgb": document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML,
    "opacity": document.getElementById("div").style.opacity
});

//pass the array into the dropdown list

var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
    for (var i = 0; i < colors[i].length; i++) {
    var opt = colors[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);

    console.log(colors);
}
}
```

I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " Here is the project jsbin.com/eXAligom/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
for (var i = 0; i < colors[i].length; i++) {
    var opt = colors[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    console.log(colors);
}
```

Comment: Never use `.innerHTML` property, especially for `<option>` elements.

Comment: Because `innerHTML` is extremely slow. And regarding `<option>` tags, there is a special property called `.text`.

Comment: I am still getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " Here is the project http://jsbin.com/eXAligom/1/

Comment: May be your colors array is undefined,

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, I would have changed the Save() function to:

```
function Save() {
colors.push({
    "name": document.getElementById("name").value,
    "rgb": document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML,
    "opacity": document.getElementById("div").style.opacity
});
//pass the array into the dropdown list
var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
    var opt = colors[colors.length-1],
        el = document.createElement("option"),
        desc = 'N: ' + (opt.name || 'unnamed') + ' RGB: ' + opt.rgb + ' O: ' + (opt.opacity || '0') ;
    el.innerHTML = desc;
    el.value = desc;
    select.appendChild(el);
    console.log(colors);}
```

The changes are pretty much self-explanatory.